# Base class Attributes reset at run time C#

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes, radix

I have a class that inherits from System.Attribute.

This class is being used to set the PageAttributes for any pages.

Is it possible to reset these attributes at runtime from a derived class?.
Changing it from the derived classes doesn't change the attributes.

I have a page level attribute set for all pages that derives from a base form. All the page level methods are written in baseform. Baseform methods were able to read the attributes defined(hardcoded) in the pages as below

```
[PageAttributeDefinition( CompleteURL = "Default.aspx")] 
public partial class Testpage: BaseForm 
{ 
}
```

Tried changing the Attribute "CompletrURL" dynamically based on a condition. I am able to create instance and set the value to the attribute. However the baseform class i am unable to read the modified attribute.

Comment: Do you have some code? Please show us what you have tried before and explain what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to change the attribute at runtime.

From [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fd3cce3-0409-4a8c-9612-551528f3ccfb/add-or-change-attribute-to-a-property-in-runtime-is-it-possible-?forum=netfxbcl):

> No, this is not possible. Remember, attributes are stored in the DLL or EXE that defines the class. So to change the value of an attribute, you are essentially asking to edit that DLL or EXE. Applications typically cannot change their own binaries while they are running.
>   ...

Comment: I have a page level attribute set for all pages that derives from a  base form. All the page level methods are written in baseform. Baseform methods  were able to read the attributes defined(hardcoded) in the pages  as below
[PageAttributeDefinition( CompleteURL = "Default.aspx")] 
public partial class Testpage: BaseForm {
}. Tried changing the Attribute "CompletrURL" dynamically based on a condition. I am able to create instance and set the value to the attribute. However the baseform class i am unable to read the modified attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot spot any problem to update an attribute at runtime. Is this what you need?

```
void Main()
{

    BaseTest test = new TestClass();
    var attr = (MyAttribute) test.GetType().GetCustomAttributes().First();  
    attr.Id = 34;

}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{   
    public int Id { get; set; } = 3;    
}
public class BaseTest { }

[My]
public class TestClass : BaseTest { }
```